# Frequency of words in all the links of a website using selenium

Tags: python, excel, selenium

I am writing code to automate the count of words for a given link using Selenium. I have provided the URL in `driver.get()`. I have used `find_elements_by_xpath` which will return a list of links. What I want to do is crawl to each the links and find the frequency of words like "Machine Learning", "Deep Learning" and print the frequency along with words in excel sheet.

I have extracted the links. How do I proceed further.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os 

driverLocation = "C:\\Users\\Shishir\\workspace\\libs\\chromedriver.exe"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = driverLocation
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverLocation)
driver.get("https://www.servicenow.com/solutions-by-category.html")

#Get elements by Xpath
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
for elem in links:
    #print all the links 
    print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
```

Comment: ...and? You forgot to ask us a **question**

Comment: oops!! My bad. I have extracted the links and how do I proceed further.

Comment: @Andersson, can u help me with this.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. You should describe your issue and provide with the code that have failed to achieve your goal, but not to ask someone to write code for you. Update ticket with your attempts